# Generic Operator Overloading in Swift

Tags: swift, generics, operator-overloading

I've been learning Swift and have a question about using Generics with Operator Overloading.  This is my requirement:

1. Have a basic generic struct that implements generic matrix functionality, having three main parameters: row:Int, column:Int and array:[T].
2. Want to implement == operator, i.e. each parameter is ==.
3. Don't want to have to duplicate operator overload functions for each type.

It seems Swift isn't smart enough to allow me to write a generic operator overload function that references the generic array [T] without some workarounds?

I have read this post: [http://www.raywenderlich.com/80818/operator-overloading-in-swift-tutorial][1] and the solution given there seems surprisingly complicated.

I just wondered what the general consensus amongst the pro's here is?
Sorry, I will post a code sample as an edit shortly.

Paul

Comment: So where's that code sample? lol...

Answer (score 2):

Here's how you can do that. Its very easy, you just need to ensure that T is Equatable.

```
struct Matrix<T> {
    // Definition goes here.
    var array = [T]()
}
func ==<T: Equatable>(lhs: Matrix<T>, rhs: Matrix<T>) -> Bool {
    return lhs.array == rhs.array 
}
```

Comment: This currently doesn't work - if either array is empty, `true` will be returned regardless of whether the other array is empty or not. It would be better to write: `return lhs.array == rhs.array`.

Comment: Sorry I forgot about that my bad