# Swift typealias in protocol and generic types

Tags: swift, protocols

I have a protocol, that has a typealias:

```
protocol Fooable {
    typealias T: Equatable
    func makeFoo() -> T
}
```

I expect, that all types, that conforms to it will return Equatable values from `makeFoo`.

Now I'd like to make an array extension, which stores `Fooable` values:

```
extension Array where Element: Fooable {

    func arrayFoo<F: Foobable, S>(array: Array<F>, transform: (Element, [F]) -> S) -> [S] {
```

I expect, that given array A, which contains `Fooable` elements and array B, which contains `Fooable` elements I can make:

```
a.arrayFoo(b, {...})
```

I have a part of `arrayFoo` function:

```
var leftGenerator = self.generate()
var rightGenerator = array.generate()

if let leftValue = leftGenerator.next(), rightValue = rightGenerator.next() {
    let leftFoo = leftValue.makeFoo()
    let rightFoo = rightValue.makeFoo()

    if leftFoo == rightFoo {
```

I expect `leftFoo` and `rightFoo` to be Equatable, because they are produced by `makeFoo()`, which should return Equatables.

But Swift complains: `Binary operator == cannot be applied to operands of type Element.T and F.T`

Any ideas or workarounds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `arrayFoo()` method, both `array` and `self` are arrays
of `Fooable` elements, but not necessarily with the same underlying
type `T`, i.e. `Element.T` and `F.T` are unrelated types.

You can fix that with an additional constraint
`where F.T == Element.T` on the type placeholders:

```
func arrayFoo<F: Fooable, S where F.T == Element.T >(array: Array<F>, transform: (Element, [F]) -> S) -> [S] {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that problem is inside `Equatable` protocol, look in it's declaration:

```
@warn_unused_result
public func ==(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Bool
```

You should override func `==` and provide some result for this, or `Swift` compiler doesn't know, hot to compare it.
You use generic type, it's not settled how to compare `Int` and `String` for example

```
let t = 0
let a = "string"
if t == a { // error
}
```

Comment: So how should I implement `==` for generic type?

Comment: I googled some nice answer here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28739567/generic-operator-overloading-in-swift You may look, I'm playing in playground for your case